# Delete All Subscribers - 10 Million Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to delete all subscribers. This is around 10 million subscribers (That is not a typo)

Can I create a group - Delete the group and select delete from all subscribers (Top Level Business Unit)

Or is there an easier or better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

So deleting from 'All Subscribers' does not remove the contacts from the account. If you want to delete them entirely from the account you would need to leverage the ['Contact Delete'](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5) process.

> Delete contacts to remove contact information from your Marketing Cloud Contact Builder account. Delete contact information to to meet data compliance regulations. This feature applies only to contacts in Email, MobileConnect, MobilePush, and Contact Builder.

Create a DE with the list of subscribers you want to delete (max of 1 mil at a time) and use that DE as the source for 'Contact Delete'

Comment: Completely correct. 
I recently learned that for such numbers, support has a standardized process.
So you could as well assemble the keys and create a support ticket.